# Can anyone recommend an elegant "No IE6 support" script?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-6

I would like to kindly and elegantly tell people who are using internet explorer 6 to either upgrade their browser or smash their computers into tiny pieces when they come to my site.

Comment: There's a cool site for "smashing IE": http://www.crashie.com/. It contains a HTML+JS code which crashes IE7 and lower. And it doesn't do anything to the other browsers.

Comment: @rhino: Sadly, there are a lot of IE users (esp. IE 6) that are not able to update their browser because of company restrictions. It would be really aggressive to kill their browsers.

Comment: @elusive, Windows98/ME (last OS to support IE6) has been unsupported for a LONG time. What companies are refusing to move to IE7?

Comment: @Brad: IE 6 was the standard-browser in Windows XP (back in 2001). Lazy sysadmins (and their bosses) are the biggest reason for IE 6 being still around.

Comment: @elusive... I see... well get those users fussing at their lazy-ass admins!

Comment: @Brad: Alright, then. Let's get it up and running!

Comment: From accessibility PoV your site is bad enough already, so IE6 user got repulsed naturally

Comment: @elusive I think that it's not worth the effort for most websites to support those lazy/backward companies... more important to build a great site for the majority of people out there who use relatively sane browsers...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check out:

- [ie6-upgrade-warning](http://code.google.com/p/ie6-upgrade-warning/)

[image]

Comment: I was going to recommend browsesad.com but I think I have a new favorite. This is much better!

Comment: The best thing about it is, that it is fully translatable.

Answer (score 2):

Use a conditional comment. :) http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: -1. Conditional comments must day... also, the OP asked for a “please upgrade” script, which serves a radically different purpose.

Comment: I find it amazing that I get voted down on this suggestion when every script solution linked uses conditional comments too. Wait til some sysadmin decides that Javascript is dangerous and disables it in your visitors' browsers and your script solutions are dead. Conditionally commenting a div would serve even if Javascript were disabled.

Comment: While conditional comments may be ok for this specific case when only one browser is targeted, this solution does not show a “please upgrade” nor it prevents IE6 user access, nor it shatters the user pc into tiny pieces

Comment: Well, this was targeted at one browser: IE6. With CSS, you can prevent interaction by making the div cover the whole screen. Just because you wanted to use a JS solution doesn't mean it's the best solution for the OP. And no, I didn't include the code for such an upgrade message. That's left as an exercise for the OP. StackOverflow != PlzSendMeTheCodeOverflow.

Comment: I have to agree with jxpx777 -- conditional comments can be used to tell ie6 users to go screw themselves.

Answer (score 1):

This is my personal favorite:  [http://ie6update.com/](http://www.ie6update.com/)

Looks suspiciously like a legit Microsoft update or Active X prompt.  That should trick the dinosaurs to adapt....

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ua = browser_info();

if (($ua['msie']==6.0)) {
    echo "PUT HERE YOUR TEXT THAT SHOULD BE DISPLAYED IN IE6";
    }else{
        echo "";
        }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need a div on your page like:

```
<div class='noAccess'>
</div>
```

and jQuery:

```
var IE6 = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 6") >= 0) ? true : false;
if (IE6) {

    $(function() {
        $("<div class='noAccess'>")
            .css({
                'height': $(window).height()
            })
            .appendTo("body");

            $("<div class='noAccessMessage'><p class='h1'>Sorry! This site doesn't support Internet Explorer 6.</p><p class='h4'>To continue, please update your browser to the latest version of FireFox or Internet Explorer using the links below.</p><table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td align='center' valign='top'>FireFox <a href='http://www.mozilla.com' target='_blank'><img src='images/Firefox-32.png' alt='FireFox' border='0' /></a><br />recommended</td><td align='center' valign='top'>Internet Explorer <a href='http://www.microsoft.com/nz/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx' target='_blank'><img src='images/IE-32.png' alt='Internet Explorer' border='0' /><a/></td></tr></table>")
            .appendTo("body");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this
http://www.ie6nomore.com/